# Follow django tutorial... wrong version

Tags: django, django-admin

Evening,

Trying to follow the Django tutorial, as seen here, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

I run the command to build start my project but I get a 'flat' folder structure.

```
nick@nick~/foo: ls
nick@nick~/foo:
```

I start with an empty dir, and then run the start project command.

```
nick@nick~/foo: django-admin.py startproject mysite
nick@nick~/foo: ls
mysite
```

so it's not flat, but the manage file is not here.... like the tutorial.

```
nick@nick~/foo: cd mysite/
nick@nick~/foo/mysite: ls
__init__.py manage.py   settings.py urls.py
nick@nick~/foo/mysite: django-admin.py --version
1.3.1
```

So, I am using the latest, but my manage is not outside the mysite folder....

Anyone know what im doing wrong here, or whats going on!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're seeing a flat structure inside the mysite directory, exactly as the warning box on the tutorial you read indicates.

This is, of course, because as you show, you're *not* using the development version - you're using version 1.3.x. So, [read the 1.3 tutorial instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: Argh! Your right. The link for the tutorial I clicked off from one of the home pages, and thought it would just be current not a dev tutorial.